# Spring security : HTTP Status 404 : The requested resource (/trade-web/login) is not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm trying to do a spring security D/B authentication example with custom service class for authentication-provider.

I'm getting HTTP 404 Status -The requested resource (/itrade-web/login) is not available.
I know its because i'm able to resolve to jsp page.I did put some sysouts in controller,but it was not getting printed.So the control is not going till controller and its going wrong just right after login url is looked up in security context xml for some reasons.

P.S - I'm not getting any error in console.

[Edit] : I'm sure that spring security hijacks the incoming request, its after that something is going wrong before the control goes back to controller from security xml which i'm not able to figure out.

Please help me out in knowing what exactly is the problem here.I've included all the codes below:

application-context-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.html"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="LoginUserDetailsService">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="LoginUserDetailsService"
    class="com.inf.trade.core.service.security.LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAOImpl" />
</bean>

<bean id="loginDAOImpl" class="com.inf.trade.core.dao.security.LoginDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory"> <ref bean ="sessionFactory"/> </property>
</bean>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.inf.trade.client.controller" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
             <value>/pages/</value>
          </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
      <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>
```

index.jsp (its inside webapp)

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/static/css/tutorial.css'/>"       type="text/css" />
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="content">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <p>
  Anyone can view this page.
  </p>
  <p><a href="welcome.html">Login page</a></p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

login.jsp (its inside webapp/pages and welcome.jsp is also inside webapp/pages)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.errorblock {
color: #ff0000;
background-color: #ffEEEE;
border: 3px solid #ff0000;
padding: 8px;
margin: 16px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password (Authentication with Database)</h3>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
        ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
    </div>
</c:if>

<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
    method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

BaseController.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "footer", "headerObject", "menuObject" })
public class BaseController {

@Autowired
private FooterDelegate footerDelegate;

@Autowired
private HeaderDelegate headerDelegate;

@Autowired
//private IMenuDelegate menuDelegate;

/*public IMenuDelegate getMenuDelegate() {
    return menuDelegate;
}

public void setMenuDelegate(MenuDelegateDirect menuDelegate) {
    this.menuDelegate = menuDelegate;
}*/

public FooterDelegate getFooterDelegate() {
    return footerDelegate;
}

public void setFooterDelegate(FooterDelegate footerDelegate) {
    this.footerDelegate = footerDelegate;
}

public HeaderDelegate getHeaderDelegate() {
    return headerDelegate;
}

public void setHeaderDelegate(HeaderDelegate headerDelegate) {
    this.headerDelegate = headerDelegate;
}

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView welcome(Model model) {


    System.out.println("Inside Welcome1");

    String userId = "hammid_hani";
    FooterModel footerVO = new FooterModel();
    footerVO.setFooterListTop(footerDelegate.readFooter(userId)
            .getFooterListTop());
    footerVO.setFooterListBottom(footerDelegate.readFooter(userId)
            .getFooterListBottom());
    model.addAttribute("footer", footerVO);




    HeaderModel headerVO = new HeaderModel();
    headerVO.setTopLeft(headerDelegate.fetchHeader(userId).getTopLeft());
    headerVO.setTopRight(headerDelegate.fetchHeader(userId).getTopRight());
    headerVO.setTickerList(headerDelegate.fetchHeader(userId)
            .getTickerList());
    model.addAttribute("headerObject", headerVO);




    MenuModel menuVO = new MenuModel();
    try {
        //menuVO.setMenuList(menuDelegate.fetchMenu(userId).getMenuList());

        model.addAttribute("menuObject", menuVO);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println("Inside Welcome");

    /*User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String name = user.getUsername();

    ModelMap mmap = new ModelMap();
    mmap.addAttribute("username", name);
    mmap.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security login + database example");*/
    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
}

//@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView login(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Inside /login...");
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
/*public String login(ModelMap model) {

    System.out.println("Inside /login...");
    return "login";

}*/

@RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";

}

@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model) {

    return "login";
}}
```

[Update] Below is the Tiles.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

  <tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="/pages/portalLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/portalHeader.jsp" /> 
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/pages/portalMenu.jsp" /> 
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/portalFooter.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="BasketOrders" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/BasketOrders.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="portfolio" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/portfolio.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="orderSummary" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/orderSummary.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="accountSummary" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/accountSummary.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Below is my SL4J configuration in pom.XML

```
    <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springsec-version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springsec-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.1</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.apache.cxf-version>2.6.5</org.apache.cxf-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>     
    <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- Logging --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[Update] Below is my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>SpringPOC</display-name>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContextDirect.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

[update] Server log on startup:

```
            SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building trade-web 0.0.1
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ trade-web >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ trade-web ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ trade-web ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ trade-web <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ trade-web ---
    [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/trade-web
    [INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\MyWorkspaces\SecurityWS\trade-web\target\tomcat
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
    INFO: Starting tomcat server
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/MyWorkspaces/SecurityWS/trade-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/karthik_chellappan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Mar 25 17:33:37 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContextDirect.xml]
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17820c3: defining beans [accountSummaryDelegate,accountSummaryServiceDelegate,accountSummaryServiceImpl,accountSummaryDAOImpl,basketOrdersDelegate,basketOrdersServiceDelegate,basketOrdersServiceImpl,basketOrdersDAOImpl,portfolioDelegate,portfolioServiceDelegate,portfolioServiceImpl,portfolioDAOImpl,orderPadDelegate,orderPadServiceDelegate,orderPadServiceImpl,orderPadDAOImpl,headerDelegate,headerServiceDelegate,headerServiceImpl,headerDAOImpl,footerDelegate,footerServiceDelegate,footerServiceImpl,footerDAOImpl,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,LoginUserDetailsService,loginDAOImpl]; root of factory hierarchy
    WARN : org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass - HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.inf.trade.core.entity.MarginRequirementsDO
    WARN : org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass - HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.inf.trade.core.entity.MarginRequirementsDO
    ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table PRDtradeDB.USER_AUTHENTICATION add access number(10,0)
    ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

    INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6196 ms
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
    INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Mon Mar 25 17:33:43 IST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1feb2ea: defining beans [accountSummaryController,baseController,basketOrdersController,ordersController,portfolioController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,tilesViewResolver,tilesConfigurer,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,jacksonObjectMapper,messageSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17820c3
    WARN : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowired annotation should be used on methods with actual parameters: public com.inf.trade.client.delegate.footer.FooterDelegate com.inf.trade.client.controller.base.BaseController.getFooterDelegate()
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer - TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]

    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/logout] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/logout.*] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/logout/] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/welcome] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/welcome.*] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/welcome/] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/login.*] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/login/] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/loginfailed] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/loginfailed.*] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/loginfailed/] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/getQuote] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/getQuote.*] onto handler 'baseController'
    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/getQuote/] onto handler 'baseController'

    INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 693 ms
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    Mar 25, 2013 5:33:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

[Update] I have log4j for logging and SL4J is the interface which uses log4j for logging. Now that i'm getting below error,ideally i shouldn't be seeing logs at all but instead i'm seeing info & warning.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I would like to know how am i seeing this i.e.does this mean log4j is enabled in-spite of SL4J error.

Comment: enable spring debug logging and check what's there?

Comment: Hi eis, thanks for your reply.SL4J logging has been enabled through maven.

Comment: post your tiles.xml code. What is your purpose of using  UrlBasedViewResolver AND InternalResourceViewResolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It was because of '.html' missing for login-page.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.html"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
        default-target-url="/welcome.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />
</security:http>
```

And it was expecting *.html because i gave the same in web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

@krisl - Thanks for your time.